# Low voltage connector identification?

Tags: connector, 12v, low-voltage

Can anyone identify the female and male connectors in the picture? Thanks[image]

---

[image]
Here are some more pics Thank you.

---

1.56mm from pin to pin. So it should be a JST 1.25mm 2 pin micro?

Comment: 2.5 mm JST? What’s the pin spaning?

Comment: It does look like a ‘JST’ connector. JST is a connector manufacturer whose connectors are copied. Depending on the pin spacing (pitch) etc it is probably something like a XH series. Go to the JST website to find the series that matches yours. The copies tend to reference the same part numbering so that should  help find something the same or functionally similar.

Comment: The pin distance is also important and better zoomed pictures from more sides. To distinguish between manufacturers each detail is interesting

Comment: 1.56mm from pin to pin. So it should be a JST 1.25mm 2 pin micro?

Answer (score 0):

The "pin spacing", is from hole to hole in the connector. So the two caliper points would go in each hole.   This does look like a "JST" to me (which is just some arbitrary designation), the JST's come in different "pitches" or "spacing" and have a corresponding female / mail header they fit into.

So once you figure out the pitch, then you are set to go order a matching connector.

Answer (score 0):

what you do is read the part number off the fan and then find the data-sheet for the fan, that will tell you what the connector is.

However given the 2mm pin spacing it does look a lot like "JST PH" is the connector series here.